# (Azure DevOps) Command Line Script .exe Console messages not visible in logs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, console-application, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to run an .exe during a release pipeline on Azure DevOps.
In order to do so, I'm using a Command Line Script task where i just "invoke" the .exe file.

It works as it's correctly launched but i cannot see the output of the .exe (that is a .net framework 4.7.2 Console Application).
I've used a simple "Console.WriteLine()" method in the Console App in order to dump the messages. Obviously, on local machine it correctly writes messages on the console output. On Azure DevOps...just the Std Errors.

Why? How could I dump application messages to the task log?

Thanks

Comment: I'm running TabularEditor as described here https://tabulareditor.github.io/2019/10/08/DevOps3.html but there is no console output (as compared to when I just run it directly)

Comment: I added ECHO ON to the start of my script and that didn't fix it. Still no cmdline output

Answer (score 0):

My bad. After different tries and retries i've found that the problem was related to a wrong dependency (resolved via reflection at runtime) that was causing exceptions before any log was written.

So, in fact, it works as expected.